# RelativeLayout works, whereas ConstraintLayout Fails

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

Here is the code from RelativeLayout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:minWidth="200dp"
            android:minHeight="200dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_description_24px"
            android:tint="@color/grey" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtInputLayoutCaption"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgSend"
        android:hint="@string/caption">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextCaption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="@font/trebuchet" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSend"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp36"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp36"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtInputLayoutCaption"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24px"
        android:tint="?attr/colorPrimary" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**RelativeLayout Output**

[image]

And here is the constraint layout code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_description_24px"
        android:tint="@color/grey"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp8"
        android:hint="@string/caption"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgSend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSend"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dp36"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dp36"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24px"
        android:tint="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtInputLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the output for constraint layout code.

[image]

Note: I'm using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2`

Comment: how about change 
from
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
to

app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/txtInputLayout"
in ImageView (imgIcon")

Comment: remove the plus symbol ("+") when you're referencing existing views in your constraints.

Comment: I believe the layout is just part of equation. When I paste your constraint layout-based sample into test project, it works and behaves as (I believe) it should - that is, soft kbd is not overlapping bottom part, everything returns to normal when keyboard is closed.

Comment: Just change `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtInputLayout"` to 
       `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to `imgSend button`

Comment: @MD, I tried that, but same result.

Comment: @ror May I know your constraint layout version?

Comment: @Gunaseelan just checked it's this: androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3

Comment: @ror In 1.1.3 it worked for me too... When I update my version, it behaves like this....

Answer (score 0):

Intention of ConstraintLayout is to optimize and flatten the view hierarchy of your layouts by applying some rules to each view to avoid nesting.

Rules remind you of RelativeLayout, for example setting the left to the bottom of some other view.

```
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/view1"
```

Unlike RelativeLayout, ConstraintLayout offers bias value that is used to position a view in terms of 0% and 100% horizontal and vertical offset relative to the handles (marked with circle). These percentages (and fractions) offer seamless positioning of the view across different screen densities and sizes.

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.33" <!-- from 0.0 to 1.0 -->
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.53" <!-- from 0.0 to 1.0 -->
```

Comment: if you want to constrain on the left you use end and start constraints and not bottom as you mention in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Give send button start constraint to **txtInputLayoutCaption**

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:minHeight="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share_active"
        android:tint="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtInputLayout"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:hint="caption"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imgSend"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgSend"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/txtInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/txtInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/txtInputLayout" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```